# How to make screenshot from web page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, screenshot, html

How to make screenshot from any url (web page)?

I was trying:

```
from .ghost import Ghost
ghost = Ghost(wait_timeout=4)
ghost.open('http://www.google.com')
ghost.capture_to('screen_shot.png')
```

Result:

```
No module named '__main__.ghost'; '__main__' is not a package
```

I was trying also:

[Python Webkit making web-site screenshots using virtual framebuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572575/python-webkit-making-web-site-screenshots-using-virtual-framebuffer)

[Take screenshot of multiple URLs using selenium (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44926240/take-screenshot-of-multiple-urls-using-selenium-python)

[Fastest way to take a screenshot with python on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586046/fastest-way-to-take-a-screenshot-with-python-on-windows)

[Take a screenshot of open website in python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563350/take-a-screenshot-of-open-website-in-python-script)

**I've also tried other methods that are not listed here.**
Nothing succeeded. Or an error or module is not found .. or or or.
I'm tired. Is there an easy way to make a screenshot of a web page using Python 3.X?

upd1:

```
C:\prg\PY\PUMA\tests>py save-web-html.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "save-web-html.py", line 2, in <module>
from .ghost import Ghost
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.ghost'; '__main__' is not a package
```

upd2:

```
C:\prg\PY\PUMA\tests>py save-web-html.py
Exception ignored in: <bound method Ghost.__del__ of <ghost.ghost.Ghost object at 0x0000020A169CF860>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Coar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\ghost\ghost.py", line 325, in __del__
    self.exit()
  File "C:\Users\Coar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\ghost\ghost.py", line 315, in exit
    self._app.quit()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'quit'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "save-web-html.py", line 4, in <module>
    ghost = Ghost(wait_timeout=4)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'wait_timeout'
```

Comment: No. save-web-html.py

Comment: pip install ghost and pip install Ghost.py | No of course

Comment: No, few py files. But no one of them named ghost.py

I was tring to find any working solution, but it always not work.

Comment: So normal?.....

Comment: C:\Users\Coar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\ghost\__init__.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the late 80's this may have been a simple task, just render some html to an image instead of the screen.

But these days web-pages require client-side execution to build parts of its DOM and re-render based on client-side initiated AJAX (or equivalent) requests... it's a whole thing "web 2.0" thing.

Rendering a web-site such as http://google.com as a simple html return should be easy, but rendering something like https://www.facebook.com/ or https://www.kogan.com/ will have many back & fourth comms to display what you're expecting to see.

So restricting this to a pure python solution may not be plausible; I'm not aware of a python-based browser.
Consider running a separate service to take the screenshots, and use your core application (in python) to fetch requested screenshots.

I just tried a few with docker, many of them struggle with `https` and the aforementioned `ajax` behaviour.

[earlyclaim/docker-manet](https://hub.docker.com/r/earlyclaim/docker-manet/) appears to work [demo page](https://manet.herokuapp.com/)

edit: from your comments, you need the data from a graph that's rendered using a 2nd request.

you just need the json return from https://www.minnowbooster.net/limit/chart

```
try:
    from urllib.request import urlopen  # py3
except ImportError:
    from urllib2 import urlopen  # py2
import json

url = 'https://www.minnowbooster.net/limit/chart'

response = urlopen(url)
data_str = response.read().decode()
data = json.loads(data_str)

print(data)
```

Comment: I'm just need collect some data information from site. This Data in the chart. So best way do this - via screenshot. But today is clearly not my day

Comment: oh!, can you share a link to the website?

Comment: https://www.minnowbooster.net/ 
I need data or chart below

Comment: No module named 'urllib2'. But I can solve this problem by other methods.
Thank you for finding this URL. We can consider the issue closed.

Comment: you must be using python3... code fixed.